# Is it correct to say "gather and collect"?

Tags: phrase-usage

The two words sound good together, however, I am not sure if it is appropriate to use them together. Suppose I was using it as "To gather and collect data".

Comment: Why would one use both?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It helps us answer if you show us what research you did on a question before posing it (please read the site tour). We can then focus on the issues remaining after your own research. In this case I have assumed you to be familiar with the most frequent definition of each word, leaving us with the nuances I have dealt with in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although often synonymous, *gather* may merely mean bringing together whereas *collect* has overtones of organising what has been gathered.

> GATHER, COLLECT, ASSEMBLE, CONGREGATE mean to come or bring together into a group, mass, or unit. GATHER is the most general term for bringing or coming together from a spread-out or scattered state.  a crowd quickly gathered COLLECT often implies careful selection or orderly arrangement. collected books on gardening ASSEMBLE implies an ordered union or organization of persons or things often for a definite purpose.  experts assembled for a conference  CONGREGATE implies a spontaneous flocking together into a crowd or huddle. congregating under a shelter
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collect)

Hence, one may gather and then collect as a implied progression from bringing together the data to organising them.

Comment: I believe your definition for 'collect' is referring almost totally to the 'I collect stamps' subsense, not the 'we collected the few remaining conkers' = 'gather' sense. Looking in 5 dictionaries, the 'gather' sense is, as I suspected, judged to be the default sense. Using it as OP does is inadvisable when 'gather and sort/arrange/collate ...' are available.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You kindly confirm what I wrote and what is in Merriam Webster and others. Thank you.  But the greater truth does not invalidate the smaller one.